# Using Dictionary In Combination With Class Module

Tags: vba, dictionary

below is my code I got from the help of a youtube guide. It looks at Counts and Amounts of sales based on an ID for each member. It works perfectly to sum up all of members Counts and Amounts.

```
Sub DictionarySum()

    'Set Worksheet Variable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Example Data")
    
    'Create Dictionary Based On ReadData Function
    Set dict = ReadData()
    
    'Write Data Back To Worksheet
    Call WriteDict(dict)

End Sub

Function ReadData()

    'Set Range Of Data
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    LastRow = ws.Range(rng.Address).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    'Loop Through All Rows Of Data
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        'Assign Values
        ID = rng.Cells(i, 1)
        MbrName = rng.Cells(i, 2)
        Cnt = rng.Cells(i, 4)
        Amt = rng.Cells(i, 5)
        
        'Check To See If ID Exists In Dictionary
        If dict.Exists(ID) = True Then
            Set cMember = dict(ID)
        Else
            Set cMember = New memberclass
            dict.Add ID, cMember
            cMember.MbrName = MbrName
        End If
        
        cMember.Amt = cMember.Amt + Amt
        cMember.Cnt = cMember.Cnt + Cnt
        
    Next i

    Set ReadData = dict

End Function


Function WriteDict(dict As Dictionary)

    RowVar = 2
    For Each key In dict
        Set cMember = dict(key)
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 7) = key
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 8) = cMember.MbrName
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 9) = cMember.Cnt
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 10) = cMember.Amt
        RowVar = RowVar + 1
    Next key

End Function
```

Below is my sample data:

| ID | Name | SaleType | Cnt | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | John | Phone | 2 | 75 |
| A002 | Tim | Phone | 5 | 100 |
| A003 | Jane | Online | 4 | 60 |
| A002 | Tim | Online | 2 | 45 |
| A003 | Jane | Phone | 5 | 125 |
| A001 | John | Online | 4 | 90 |

But what I want to be able to do is throw in another qualifier, called "SaleType" and be able to call to a members sales just a certain SaleType. Essentially instead of outputting "cMember.Cnt", I want to be able to do something like "cMember.SaleType("Phone").Cnt" Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is an attempt at a nested dictionary approach, it errors out when attempting to loop through the innerkeys. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix?

```
Sub Nested()

Set outer = New Dictionary

'Set Worksheet Variable
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Example Data")

'Set Range Of Data
Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
LastRow = ws.Range(rng.Address).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For j = 0 To 1
    If j = 0 Then WantSaleType= "Phone"
    If j = 1 Then WantSaleType= "Online"
        
    'Loop Through All Rows Of DatA
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Set inner = New Dictionary
            'Assign Values
            ID = rng.Cells(i, 1)
            MbrName = rng.Cells(i, 2)
            SaleType = rng.Cells(i, 3)
            Cnt = rng.Cells(i, 4)
            Amt = rng.Cells(i, 5)
            If SaleType <> WantSaleTypeThen GoTo NextRow
            
            'Check To See If ID Exists In Dictionary
            If inner.Exists(ID) = True Then
                Set cMember = inner(ID)
            Else
                Set cMember = New memberclass
                inner.Add ID, cMember
                cMember.MbrName = MbrName
            End If
            
            cMember.Amt = cMember.Amt + Amt
            cMember.Cnt = cMember.Cnt + Cnt
            
NextRow:
    Next i
    
    outer.Add WantSaleType, inner
    
Next

Dim outerkey As Variant
Dim innerkey As Variant

For Each outerkey In outer.Keys
    
    RowVar = 2
    For Each innerkey In outer(outerkey)
        Set cMember = outer(outerkey)(innerkey)
        'Debug.Print key, cMember.Amt, cMember.Cnt
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 6) = outerkey
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 7) = innerkey
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 8) = cMember.MbrName
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 9) = cMember.Cnt
        ws.Cells(RowVar, 10) = cMember.Amt
        RowVar = RowVar + 1
    Next innerkey
    
Next outerkey

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried? I would recommend a formula especially if you can't write the VBA by yourself.

Comment: @HackSlash I had a feeling it was possible, I have been using VBA for years for automation but never have used class modules. Ive been trying random attempts to put things together to make it work and watched quite a few videos on Class Modules, but nothing specific enough to what im attempting. Any advice or direction would be helpful, I feel like I have most of it done already in the code above.

Comment: Well, start by tracking the `SaleType`. Your code doesn't even have a variable for that. Once it does, you can filter on it. `If cMember.SaleType = "Phone" Then`

Comment: A dictionary of dictionaries is quite a common data structure. Your data would appear to be eminently suited to such a structure.

Comment: Where is the class module defined?

Comment: @HackSlash yes I can add lines like `cMember.ClmType = ClmType` but I feel like I shouldn't need to specify a statement like `If cMember.SaleType = "Phone" Then` because  I would want that to be variable, what happens if 12 more possible SaleTypes get added to the data. Isn't there a way to account for that just like I dont need to write code for each different member name?  Currently the class module only has the fields defined like this:

`Public ID As String`
`Public MbrName As String`
etc...

Comment: @masonhoward2 This is more of a design\architecture\engineering question. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using filters rather than VBA.

Comment: @freeflow I'm not sure what you mean by using filters, but this is going to be part of a much larger automated process for a lot of reporting, trying to be as efficient as possible and love the use of dictionaries, juts not great with them or class modules yet. I looked into nested dictionaries as you suggested and edited my post to contain the what I created, although it isnt working, any suggestions?

Comment: Also @hackslash, thanks for the advice, if you have anything to comment on my new code in the edit of the post, please let me know!

Comment: @masonhoward2 When working with Excel it is always best to delegate the heavy lifting to existing functionality in Excel as this will always be faster than a pure VBA solution. I'd strongly suggest you start googling 'using filters in excel' because your comments on being unfamiliar with dictionaries and not being sure what I mean by filtering probably means you are not competent to achieve your stated project goal.

Comment: @freeflow lol everyone has to start somewhere, right? I'm not trying to prove my competence here, I'm attempting to learn and gain new skills. I have been reading and watching tutorials left and right, but some things just require the help of an actual person once in awhile so that's why I am here. I have been using excel in my role for 7 years and vba for 5 or so of those years. Im not new to coding, just some structures and objects. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I was quite serious in my suggestion. However, if you are determined to proceed then I hope you have success despite my pessimistic outlook.